# PHP : Undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I just downloaded the new `xampp` and try to run my old projects and I got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in F:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php on line 17
```

Does it mean that the `mysql_connect` that I used is not already supported in new xampp ?

Comment: The MySQL extension has been deprecated for some years now, and was removed in PHP7.... you really should be using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: It has been removed in PHP 7, you should use PDO or Mysqli to interact with mysql databases. Mysql_* functions have been deprecated for quite some time.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul That doesn't seem to be the right duplicate, it doesn't say anything about PHP 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mysql_connect()
```

has been removed from PHP7, which is used by the newest xampp version.

Instead, use [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) like in this example.

Another method, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) is also possible (but is coded in a very different way as mysql_connect.)

Comment: Using PDO [is really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html)..

Comment: I didn't say it is difficult ;) I only said it was different from `mysqli_connect` in terms of coding :p

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL module is depreciated in `PHP5` and removed in PHP7, you can use these:

- **MySQLi** http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- **PHP::PDO** http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Check your version by using `phpinfo()`.

Comment: While correct the problem here is that mysql_* has been removed from PHP 7, not that it's deprecated from PHP 5

Comment: there are so many question available like that on SO...

Comment: @Barmar: you are genius in modification.... thumbs up

Comment: I know, quite depressing to see how many still haven't jumped on PDO/mysqli. They were introduced when, more than 10 years ago? At least the next couple of years will clean up some of the old mess - with PHP 7 being rolled out

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly by xamppp but php itself deprecated mysql Here a quote from them:

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions

if you can provide us php version i can help more