# MySQL PHP5 conflict

Tags: php, mysql, yum, php-5.6

I upgraded the php on my server. Now when I attempt to connect to the mysql server via php I get the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

So I ran

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

This is what I got:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
 --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.17-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: mysql_connect() is deprecated

Comment: what do I use? @davejal

Comment: Should it be `sudo yum install php5-mysql`?

Comment: @Tristan I get : No package php5-mysql available.

Comment: Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: no check your php file, their you're using msql_connect, you should rewrite all places where you see mysql_ . Look for `mysqli` or `pdo` tutorials

Comment: Create a php.ini File On public_html and Type extension=php_mysql.dll;

Comment: As @RajeshJNair already stated, yes there is a simple solution, but it would be moving the problem, to a bigger problem. One you rather not have.

Comment: Not a Bigger Problem at all .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Create a php.ini File On public_html 
and Type extension=php_mysql.dll;

and Save

Comment: don't suggest using mysql_ finctions anymore, as it is deprecated and easier for sql injection!

Comment: he asked for a quick solution thus why said. @davejal is correct about the security breach

Comment: Just because it's a quick solution doesn't mean it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: I did this and the mysqli_connect function is still not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [PHP : Undefined function mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34557221/3664960)

```
mysql_connect()
```

has been removed from PHP7, which is used by the newest php version.

Instead, use [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) like in this example.

Another method, [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) is also possible (but is coded in a very different way as mysql_connect.)

Comment: I can see he will just go to mysqli without even using Prepared Statements...

Comment: I added the pdo, hopefully he will use that one